# Javascript: Is it possible to Capture multiple photos before displaying in web browser the photos?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Javascript: Is it possible to Capture photos then displaying in web browser the photos? I am using dropzone.js but it seems it can't do what I need.

My project is for the mobile camera to capture photos continuously before displaying to the browser.. what i'm getting is that the browser is only taking one picture then displaying

Comment: Almost anything is possible.  Would you please rephrase your question

Comment: My project is for the mobile camera to capture photos continuously before displaying to the browser.. what i'm getting is that the browser is only taking one picture then displaying. Sorry for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using something like below, this will open the camera on mobile.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="story_avatar" capture="camera" accept="image/*"/>
<img src="empty.png" id="image-item" />
```

JS

```
$('#story_avatar').change(function() { // this is the file input
    readURL(this);
});
```

and update an img element to contains the file info

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image-item').attr('src', e.target.result); //img element
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

edited

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry my problem is not answered
Sir, this is what i want in my project:
"The camera in mobile won't go back until the user will press 'Back' in the phone.. He can capture photo as many as he wants, and when he gets back to browser, the photos he captured will be displayed, ready to be uploaded"

Comment: Humm i see. May be you will need to take stream video and send to server before show. What i know camera mobile on browsers will delegate the stream to browser until you check the taken picture.

Comment: Although this question is at best confused, your code solved my problem. So I'm not sure if I can upvote it, but thanks. :)